# Way to transfer 2 Bytes of data while through connecting to tcp server

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am searching for a way how to force to send 2 Bytes of data while connecting to server.

```
connect(m_Socket, (sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(sockaddr))
```

I need to save as much latency as possible, so I'm looking for a way to send data at once while connecting so it doesn't do roundtrip.

Sending a message after the connecting is **not** what I am looking for.

What I am looking for:

- There needs to be way how to send 2 Bytes of data with connect request and decode them on the server-side while doing `accept()`

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935958/data-payload-in-a-tcp-ack indicates your OS may avoid the roundtrip for you. If it receives a write/send/sendmsg call soon enough after the `connect` call has completed, it may piggyback the data on your last ACK of the TCP handshake.

Comment: connection and ACK in this case is something different, i am speaking about altering TCP packet frame that will send data with connection request

Comment: `connect` involves a TCP handshake that ends with an ACK packet. You can piggyback data onto the last ACK (effectively packing data with the connect request) if you make your `write`/`send`/`sendmsg` syscall within a certain small time window since the completion of your `connect` syscall. The data can be read, by the server, with a `read`/`recv`/`recvmsg` that follows a completed `accept`, though it will have arrived by the time `accept` has returned.

Comment: Also note that SYN packets with data is a known attack vector and some router/appliances may drop any such packets it detects.